# Can we characterize the set formed by cyclic vectors of a companion matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, cyclic-decomposition

Let $C$ be a matrix in [companion form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). Let us form a subset of general linear map $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ by
\begin{align*}
\mathcal E = \{G \in GL_n(\mathbb R): G = (g_1, Cg_1, \dots, Cg_1^{n-1})\},
\end{align*}
where the first column $g_1$ of $G$ is a cyclic vector of $G$, i.e., $\{g_1, Cg_1, \dots, C^{n-1} g_1\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^n$. Obviously, $\lambda I \in \mathcal E$ for any $\lambda \mathbb R^{\times}$.

Can we classify this set? In particular, what are the topological properties we can say (open or closed, connected, etc) in the Euclidean topology?